# Differential forms in projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus, amplituhedron

I am currently reading some paper about the Amplituhedron, and it is using projective geometric way to present amplitudes.

How can we define forms in projective space to measure volume for a polytope?